# How to get objects from Algolia to my android kotlin app

Tags: android, kotlin, algolia

I want to get all objects with "score" == 0  using kotlin

[image: 1]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can filter list like `val filteredList = yourList.filter { data -> data.score == 0 }`

Comment: val index = client.initIndex(IndexName(Constants.PRODUCTS_INDEX_PRICE_ASCENDING))
        var queryy = Query(
            query = "score: 0",
            attributesToRetrieve =
            listOf(
                Attribute("name"), Attribute("location"), Attribute("score"), Attribute("logoUrl")
            )
        )
        index.search(query)